# CakePHP 3 how to edit user without changing password (hashed)

Tags: forms, validation, model, cakephp-3.0

I have my UsersController with my edit.ctp view. When I browse /users/edit/1, I see password field filled with ***** (filled with hash in entity User.php, using DefaultPasswordHasher). My UsersTable.php has password has required.

So, I can try:

```
unset($user->password); // in edit() from UsersController.php
```

and setting [require => false] in edit.ctp

When I save, I get

```
The user could not be saved. Please, try again.
```

Because in my UsersTable.php I have:

```
$validator
    ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('password');
```

If I try to leave blank from controller I get error, if I try to fill with actual password, it hashes again.

How could I edit any user without change his password? Can I set this from model or I need to make password as not required?

- I don't need show the real password to admins
- I validate from controller for password_confirm (already works)
- In add.ctp there is no problem because default value is always blank
- I want to change password only if password field is filled
- I suppose **password** needs to be **required** in Model because all users need their passwords, that's why I'm trying to keep it far from validation in controller
- Validation says "on create" but even in update is needed, bug possible?
- My cake version is 3.4.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

Firstly, if you haven't already, **you may want to mark the password field as [hidden](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-properties)** to prevent it from exposing the hash in `toArray` calls or JSON views.

Secondly, **any data field provided to patchEntity will be validated** and saved (as you've discovered), **even if the value for the field is blank**.

If you look at the entity with `debug($user)` you'll notice it tracks which fields are "dirty", and since patchEntity saw you submitted a password field (even if it was blank), it set the User entity's `password` to blank and marked it as "dirty". Even if you later call `unset($user->password)` it's still got a record of it being dirty, and so it'll attempt to validate a value for it.

You could potentially mark the field clean with `$export->setDirty('password', false);` but then when a new password was submitted in the form it wouldn't be saved.

A better option would be to **check if the password field was blank before calling patchEntity, and unset it then**:

```php
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    $data = $this->request->getData();
    if(empty($data['password'])){
        unset($data['password']);
    }
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $data);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, I've updated the unset before patchEntity, in my debug(user) only appeared as "dirty" password_confirm (I think is weird) but with this all works as planned, I have _hidden in Entity 'password' and 'token', I've put value to '' in form form password (token doesn't matter really). Have a nice day :)